# how to get the return of pywhatkit.info() method into a variable

Tags: python

I am trying to get the output of the function into a variable instead of just putting it into the console

output = pywhatkit.info(search, lines=15)

but it is not working,
it just displays the texts in the cmd console instead of putting the result into the variable.
any kind of help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit/blob/b6ce91f3be88d6388b622bf15a9add897d192dfd/pywhatkit/mainfunctions.py#L149), you could see that `pywhatkit.info` function is just delegating it's parameters to `wikipedia.summary` and displaying it's result to the console.

```
def info(topic,lines=3):
    '''Gives information on a topic from wikipedia.'''
    spe = wikipedia.summary(topic, sentences = lines)
    print(spe)
```

So if you want to get the result of `pywhatkit.info` into a variable, all you need to implement the following

```
output = wikipedia.summary(search, sentences=15)
```

Alternatively you can use [`contexlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) to redirect the stdout into a buffer.

```
>>> from contextlib import redirect_stdout
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> 
>>> buffer = StringIO()
>>> with redirect_stdout(buffer):
...     pywhatkit.info(search, lines=15)
... 
>>> buffer.getvalue()
<Output will appear here>
```